# How to eleminate localhost.log files in tomcat application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

My application is daily writing localhost-date.log and writing logs related with org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext for example:

```
Jan 09, 2017 11:47:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 09, 2017 11:47:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/contex/ContextCleanupListener
```

Here's my logging.properties tomcat config:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,  2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

 java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
 java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter =java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

 # For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
 # messages:
 #org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE
 #org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE
 #org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = FINE
 #org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.level=FINE
```

I don't want any localhost log file instead of I want to write the above error in Catalina or Application log.

May I know how to do this?

Comment: This site lives from questioning answering and accepting flow. That's what people drives to participate. Since you are new here please don't forget to accept an answer see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more details. But don't get my wrong it doesn't means you have to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the `Handler specific properties` section you are defining 2 file handlers (`1catalina` and `2localhost`).

In the `Facility specific properties` section you are setting the level `.level` and the handler `.handler` for each logger.

To remove the `localhost.XXXX-XX-XX.log` files and log to the `catalina.XXXX-XX-XX.log` file you have to do the following steps.

1. Remove (delete or comment in) the localhost file handler.

   ```
   #2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
   #2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
   #2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.
   ```
2. Set the catalina file handler

   ```
   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
   ```